# Как разместить шорткод в wordpress после загрузки страницы при помощи JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Имею плагин, который выводится шорткодом [azaza="x" trololo="y"]. После определения параметров X и Y хочу вывести шорткод в область виджета. Идеальный вариант

```
document.querySelector("#text-1 > div.textwidget").innerHTML = [azaza="1" trololo="999"]
//в данном случае 1 и 999 я получил при определенных условиях. Эти значения будут всегда разные, а
//плагин адекватно реагирует на значения 1 и 999, т.к. это всего лишь его настройки,
//которые в нем предусмотрены автором плагина.
```

Если я пишу таким образом, то шорткод остается текстом, либо не в тот блок вставляю, либо что-то упускаю.

Comment: Цель достичь удалось, я взял не шорткод, а настройки в самом плагине и вышеупомянутым методом добавил innerHTML. В принципе можно было бы закрыть вопрос, но из любопытства хочу послушать мнение того, кто разбирается в данном вопросе. Может есть способ элегантнее.

Comment: Шорткоды обрабатываются в  php, выводить их надо в бэкенде.